# Parsing variables in ansible inventory in python

Tags: python-2.7, ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to parse ansible variables using python specified in an inventory file like below:

```
[webservers]
foo.example.com type=news
bar.example.com type=sports

[dbservers]
mongodb.local type=mongo region=us
mysql.local type=mysql region=eu
```

I want to be able to parse `type=news` for host foo.example.com in webservers and `type=mongo region=us` for host mongodb.local under dbservers. Any help with this is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The play below

```
- name: List type=news hosts in the group webservers
  debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[item].inventory_hostname }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['webservers'] }}"
  when: hostvars[item].type == "news"

- name: List type=mongo and region=us hosts in the group dbservers
  debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[item].inventory_hostname }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['dbservers'] }}"
  when:
    - hostvars[item].type == "mongo"
    - hostvars[item].region == "us"
```

gives:

```
"msg": "foo.example.com"
"msg": "mongodb.local"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than re-inventing the wheel, I suggest you have a look at [how ansible itsef is parsing ini files to turn them into an inventory object](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/inventory/ini.py)

You could also easily get this info in json format with a very simple playbook (as suggested by @vladimirbotka), or rewrite your [inventory in yaml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/yaml.html) which would be much easier to parse with any external tool

inventory.yaml

```
---
all:
  children:
    webservers:
      hosts:
        foo.example.com:
          type: news
        bar.example.com:
          type: sports
    dbservers:
      hosts:
        mongodb.local:
          type: mongo
          region: us
        mysql.local:
          type: mysql
          region: eu
```

Answer (score 0):

If the playbook will be run on the host:

> foo.example.com

you can get "type = news" simply by specifying "{{type}}". If you want to use in "when" conditions, then simply indicating "type"
If the playbook will be run on the host:

> mongodb.local

then the value for "type" in this case will automatically be = "mongo", and "region" will automatically be = "us"

The values of the variables, if they are defined in the hosts file as you specified, will automatically be determined on the specified hosts

Thus, the playbook can be executed on all hosts and if you get a value for "type", for example:

```
- debug:
     msg: "{{type}}"
```

On each of the hosts you will get your unique values that are defined in the hosts file

I'm not sure that I understood the question correctly, but if it meant that on the foo.example.com host it was necessary to get a list of servers from the "webservers" group that have "type = news", then the answer is already given.